# Transaction with hash ........ not found in db

Tags: monerod, daemon, error-log

Hey guys so I was syncing the chain again.

At some point sync started showing:

---

I transaction with hash .... not found in db. (5x of these lines)

I transaction added to pool.

---

Does this mean anything?

Also at around the 50% sync mark it completely stopped, the last line showed:

Killed

So I tried running monerod again and this time it shows:

Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081.

I checked that I could still ping Google.

Comment: How much ram do you have? It usually errors out like that when there's not enough ram to continue.

Comment: Okay so when I restarted it it started syncing normally. Again.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?